# What do you call a person who has the ability to question and is curious about right things?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who has the ability to question and is curious about right things? As in someone who points out loopholes in an argument or the like.

Comment: Answer is: a child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*perspicacious* [definiton](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/perspicacious):

> Having a ready insight into and understanding of things.

Comment: +1. But if you enter *'perspicacious' synonyms* in Google, you will get a list of 21 other words which seem equally apt in the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

A person to whom seeking out cavils in other people's statements and arguments is a source of rich joy is called:

- **a pedant**: a person who overemphasizes rules or minor details
- **a pharisee**: a sanctimonious, self-righteous, or hypocritical person

A person who questions other people's arguments and insists on finding his or her own answer can be called:

- **an explorer**: a person who investigates unknown regions, not necessarily geographical
- **a pioneer**: one who is first or among the earliest in any field of inquiry, enterprise, or progress
- **a pathfinder**: a person who finds or makes a path, way, route, etc.
- **a trailblazer**: a pioneer in any field of endeavor

All definitions are from [The Comprehensive Online Dictionary](http://dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be describing a "Skeptic" or "critical thinker"

If you are looking for an adjective, these might work:

Skeptical

Critical

Inquisitive